# Quickjob MOVZON X'FF' to OFA1

Tags: mainframe

what does MOVZON X'FF' do in quickjob. I believe it just moves input to output. Please let me know, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This [reference](https://supportcontent.ca.com/cadocs/0/b024371e.pdf) is used.

[image: Snip of manual page for MOVZON]

---

Given the instruction:

> > MOVZON X'FF' to OFA1

The receiving field `OFA1` refers to the first record position (the `1`) of the output file ( the `OF`) designated as `A`. The instruction will set the high-order bits (0-3 or "zone bits") of the first position to ones, matching bits 0-3 of the `X'FF'`.

However, it appears, as a matter of style, the instruction should have been written as `MOVZON X'F0' TO OAF1` since the low-order bits (4-7) are not used.

Comment: Whether or not the target field is signed or unsigned, or whether is really is a numeric field cannot be said from that MOVZON alone. MOVZON moves left halves (nibbles) of bytes from source to target. That‘s it. Right halves remain untouched.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I too reffered that manual. Thats the only answer I got from google. However, the manual doesnt provide much value for my quesiton.

Comment: @Rick: Just a minor comment. I would talk about „bytes“ not „characters“ in this context.

Comment: @phunsoft -  Page 2-16 of the referenced document uses "positions". I was more comfortable with _character_ than with _byte_, but had not considered _position_ until after posting the change. I will use the same term as the document.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest unit of information is the bit. Processors usually don‘t work on single bits when accessing memory; they work on bytes. A byte consists of 8 consecutive bits (for most architectures).

To describe how different processor instructions work with bytes, bytes are sometimes subdivided into two 4-bit groups, called **nibbles**. Counting left to right, bits 0-3 are called „left nibble“, „high order nibble“, or „**zone nibble**“. Bits 4-7, the right half, are called „right nibble“, „low order nibble“, or „**number nibble**“.

There are instructions that work on the whole byte, e.g. MOVE. And there are instructions that work on **nibbles**. MOVEZONE (MOVZON) works on **zone nibbles** and leaves the **number nibbles** alone; MOVENUM (MOVNUM) works on **number nibbles**, and leaves the **zone nibbles** alone.

This kind of instructions are usually used with bytes that contain numeric values, coded as either *zoned decimal*, or *packed decimal*. They are rather exotic when working on text data.